# angularjs ng-show not displaying as expected

Tags: angularjs

I'm probably getting confused with mvc and angularjs and trying to set a boolean to control a scope variable to hide a div.

I have a list html page that includes this:

```
 <tbody>{{isAuthorised}}
            <tr ng-repeat="calendarEvent in items" id="event_{{calendarEvent.Id}}">
                <td><strong>{{calendarEvent.EventTitle}}</strong><br/>{{calendarEvent.EventDescription}}</td>
                <td>{{calendarEvent.EventDate | date:mediumDate}}</td>
                <td><img src="{{calendarEvent.ThumbnailUrl}}" alt="" width="100" /></td>
                <td>
                    <div ng-show="isAuthorised"> 
                        <a href="#/edit/{{calendarEvent.Id}}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
                        <a ng-click="delete()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

I'm outputting the value currently to try to figure out what is going on.  So if I hit this page with setting the value the div shows my edit and delete buttons which I don't want.  The value of the scope variable displays as {}.

I have this app.js code:

```
 var ListCtrl = function ($scope, $location, CalendarEvent, SharedService) {

    ** lots of stuff removed as irrelevant **

        $scope.isAuthorised = SharedService.get();
    };
```

My login controller via a separate html content section that is setting the value (in the shared service)

```
var LoginCtrl = function ($scope, $location, $http, SharedService) {

    $scope.login = function () {
        $http.get("/AuthorisedUser/IsValidUser/" + $scope.item.ValidEmailAddress + "/")
        .success(function (result) {
            var isAuthorised = result.toLowerCase();
            if (isAuthorised) {
                SharedService.set(isAuthorised);
                $location.path('/');
            } else {
                alert('you do not have the power!');
            }

        })
        .error(function() {
             alert('Email could not be Validated at this time');
        });

    }
};
```

the result is an MVC method returning a bool type.  I thought maybe I needed to convert the bool to lower case because javascript would like it better, but maybe that's doing some implicit conversion to a string or something?!  I'm not sure what I need to change in my list html to properly show that div only when the value is true.  I'm coming from a .NET background with limited AngularJS understanding.

The value seems to being set, because if I put in a valid email address I'm seeing

true

in the html page where the scope variable is.

It seemed to work once in Chrome - but now that's not working, and just showing the stuff that should be hidden.

Sorry forgot to include the shared service:

```
EventsCalendarApp.factory('SharedService', function() {
    var savedData = {}

    function set(data) {
        savedData = data;
    }

    function get() {
        return savedData;
    }

    return {
        set: set,
        get: get
    }
});
```

Comment: Make a fiddle with the problem.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what that means.

Comment: If you're talking about somehow using jsfiddle.net to replicate the problem I'm not sure how to convert what I've got into a simple html and javascript sections as I've got two html pages (in a SPA) calling a MVC controller. I'm not sure that by hacking the values that I'll be reproducing my current scenario.

Comment: first of all why don't you check your email id is valid or not at inputing time. if email id is valid ,allow user to go ahead. else don't allow.

Comment: I have a single page application that is maintaining a calendar of events, it's just a quick and dirty app, but I want to "lock it down" - so I've added authorised email addresses to a database, so I want the user to have to validate their email address once, and then be able to edit and add what they like.

Comment: what does your SharedService.set(isAuthorised) do? Please be clear with what you want to do?

Comment: Sorry - forgot to include that code.  Was trying not to post everything as it would be massive :)  @micronyks added now

Comment: Tried using jsfiddle.net example but I don't know how to replicate the calling of my list control.  Usually in the browser I just navigate to index.html#/list to call that.  (Sorry - new to angular JS)

Comment: that's fine jen. Now please tell me what do you want to do? tell me specific action like if i get this data, i want this should be done or if that data, that should be done... 
in SharedService.set(isAuthorised); isAuthorised gets boolean value. and you pass it to data variable in function. so ultimately your saveData gets boolean value. i'm myself confused. please be clear now.

Comment: @micronyks Sorry.  I have login form where user puts in email address.  This calls an MVC controller via the loginCtrl login method.  if the email address is found in db the MVC controller returns boolean of true.  Value was "True" so converted it to lower case.  If value is true then I set it in the shared service and update singe page app to show list of events.  On my ListCtrl I retrieve from shared service to set in that scope to determine hide or show add/edit and delete links on page. I was trying to achieve this using the ng-show on the div surrounding the links, but they always show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think everything would be simplified in your controller, service, and UI if your service dealt with object references rather than a Boolean value (which is a primitive).

Your service:

```
EventsCalendarApp.factory('SharedService', function() {
    var savedData = { isAuthorised: false }

    function set(data) {
        // overwrites savedData properties with data's properties, 
        // but preserves the reference
        angular.copy(data, savedData);
    }
    function setAuthorised(authorised) {
        savedData.isAuthorised = authorised;
    }

    function get() {
        return savedData;
    }

    return {
        set: set,
        get: get,
        setAuthorised: setAuthorised
    }
});
```

Your Login controller:

```
var LoginCtrl = function ($scope, $location, $http, SharedService) {

    // helper function to determine if str contains 'true'
    function parseBoolean(str) {
          return /^true$/i.test(str);
    }        
    $scope.login = function () {
        $http.get("/AuthorisedUser/IsValidUser/" + $scope.item.ValidEmailAddress + "/")
        .success(function (result) {
            var isAuthorised = parseBoolean(result);
            if (isAuthorised) {
                SharedService.set({ isAuthorised: isAuthorised });
                // OR
                SharedService.setAuthorised(isAuthorised);

                $location.path('/');
            } else {
                alert('you do not have the power!');
            }

        })
        .error(function() {
             alert('Email could not be Validated at this time');
        });

    }
};
```

Your List Controller:

```
 var ListCtrl = function ($scope, $location, CalendarEvent, SharedService) {

    ** lots of stuff removed as irrelevant **

        $scope.savedData = SharedService.get();
    };
```

HTML:

```
<tbody>{{savedData.isAuthorised}}
            <tr ng-repeat="calendarEvent in items" id="event_{{calendarEvent.Id}}">
                <td><strong>{{calendarEvent.EventTitle}}</strong><br/>{{calendarEvent.EventDescription}}</td>
                <td>{{calendarEvent.EventDate | date:mediumDate}}</td>
                <td><img ng-src="{{calendarEvent.ThumbnailUrl}}" alt="" width="100" /></td>
                <td>
                    <div ng-show="savedData.isAuthorised"> 
                        <a href="#/edit/{{calendarEvent.Id}}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
                        <a ng-click="delete()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

When you use object references, then any changes to the reference from within your service is automatically propagated to the views; as do any changes to the reference that happen inside a controller.  There is no real magic behind this - they are automatically updated because they are the same reference.  In contrast, when you use primitives, then a copy of the value is passed around, and it becomes more challenging to keep them all in synch.

> NOTE: on an unrelated note, you should use ng-src for image URLs that are binding expressions. This ensures that the image URL is only downloaded by the browser after the expression is evaluated and rendered.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation.  This seems a lot neater than my solution.  Good to also know about ng-src :)

Comment: np:) The reason that a string is returned from your IsValidUser Web API call is because it is returning a primitive. If you return a Result object instead (ie. class Result { bool IsAuthorised { get;set; } }) then there would be no need to cast. A Result object can be jsonified, but a primitive return value cannot.

Answer (score 0):

```
var LoginCtrl = function ($scope, $location, $http, SharedService) {

$scope.login = function () {
    $http.get("/AuthorisedUser/IsValidUser/" + $scope.item.ValidEmailAddress + "/")
    .success(function (result) {

        $scope.isAuthorised = result.toLowerCase();

    })
    .error(function() {
         alert('Email could not be Validated at this time');
    });

}
```

};

Keep one thing in mind you $scope works as a bridge between controller and view. if your controller update $scope, your view gets changed. 
Don't use sharedservice here. its useless for what you want to do. try my above snippet.

Comment: I thought because I'm going between two controllers that the scope gets reset.  Ie. I set the value in the login controller, but I then update the single page app to show the list of events, which then calls the list controller and searches, etc..

Comment: So I updated the loginCtrl to set the $scope.isAuthorised with the value, and I removed the $scope.isAuthorised = SharedService.get() line from the ListCtrl.  That stopped the add/edit/delete links from ever displaying (even after putting in a valid email address via logging in).  If I put back the $scope.isAuthorised = SharedService.get() it seemed to work for the true/false values as expected.  Unless I hard refresh my page in which case it shows {} as the value of the scope variable and shows the add/edit/delete links.

Comment: Initialising the value on my listCtrl if it doesn't have a value in the shared service seems to have done the trick. Added it as an answer to not confused my original post.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was to update the ListCtrl to have this logic:

```
var ListCtrl = function ($scope, $location, CalendarEvent, SharedService) {
    var authorised = SharedService.get();
    if (authorised != "true")
        $scope.isAuthorised = false;
    else
        $scope.isAuthorised = SharedService.get();
};
```

It now seems to be working! I'm still confused about the handling of booleans in javascript as I seem to have a mix of boolean and string going on in the various methods.

Comment: @micronyks I'd be happy to learn the correct way!  I'm not sure which part you're saying is wrong?  The other answer doesn't work for me, and from what I've read trying to share data between multiple controllers requires a shared service.

Comment: No I'm not saying you're code is wrong. it is correct and everything you have set up is correct. I just said this is not correct approach though.You could have better solution still. But as you are learning, and you will have better command as you progress. so its fine. enjoy your coding !

Comment: Thanks @micronyks having done windows development for yonks it's quite a challenge getting back into the web stuff :)